# Is it possible obtain an identity of the type $\dfrac{|x-y|}{t} + \dfrac{|y-z|}{s} \approx a(t,s) | y - b(t,x,s,z)| + c(t,s)|x-z|$?

Tags: reference-request, inequalities, geometric-inequalities

using the Euclidean inner product, and by completing squares it is possible to prove that
$$\dfrac{|x-y|^2}{t} + \dfrac{|y-z|^2}{s} = \dfrac{t+s}{ts} \left| y - \dfrac{sx+tz}{s+t} \right|^2 + \dfrac{|x-z|^2}{t+s}, $$
for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $t,s>0.$
I want to know if it is possible to achieve some equality, or similar inequality without the squares in the norm, that is
$$\dfrac{|x-y|}{t} + \dfrac{|y-z|}{s} \approx a(t,s) \left| y - b(t,x,s,z) \right| + c(t,s)|x-z|,   $$

Comment: You are using $b$ for both a function of four variables and a function of two variables in the same equation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Fixed up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$L:=\frac{|x-y|}{t} + \frac{|y-z|}{s} \quad\text{and}\quad 
R:=a(t,s) \left| y - b(t,x,s,z) \right| + c(t,s)|x-z|.$$

Since $|x-y|\le|y-z|+|x-z|$, you get
$$L \le R$$
for all $x,y,z$ with $a(t,s):=\frac1t+\frac1s$, $b(t,x,s,z):=z$, and $c(t,s):=\frac1t$.

Similarly, since $|x-z|\le|x-y|+|y-z|$, you get
$$L \ge R$$
for all $x,y,z$ with $a(t,s):=\frac12\,\min(\frac1s,\frac1t)$, $b(t,x,s,z):=z$, and $c(t,s):=\frac12\,\min(\frac1s,\frac1t)$.

However, you cannot get the identity
$$L=R$$
for all $x,y,z$ with any $a(t,s)$, $b(t,x,s,z)$, and $c(t,s)$,
because $R$ is differentiable in $y$ at all points $y$ except maybe the one point $b(t,x,s,z)$, whereas $L$ is not differentiable in $y$ at the two distinct points $x$ and $z$ if $x\ne z$.